# Количество последних не уникальных строк

Tags: sql, postgresql

Есть три таблицы:

**users**

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | name1 |
| 2 | name2 |
| 3 | name3 |

**posts**

| id | title |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | post1 |
| 2 | post2 |
| 3 | post3 |

**comments**

| id | post_id | user_id | text |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 1 | text |
| 2 | 3 | 3 | text |
| 3 | 1 | 2 | text |
| 4 | 3 | 1 | text |
| 5 | 2 | 1 | text |
| 6 | 2 | 2 | text |
| 7 | 3 | 1 | text |
| 8 | 2 | 3 | text |
| 9 | 3 | 1 | text |
| 10 | 2 | 1 | text |
| 11 | 2 | 1 | text |

Мне надо узнать количество последних комментариев которые оставил один и тот же юзер в рамках поста, и id последнего комментария. Желательно в одном запросе. Но можно использовать подзапросы, окна и все что угодно из стандартного набора.
На примере вышеописанных таблиц результат будет следующий:

| comment_id | last_user_comments_count |
| --- | --- |
| 11 | 2 |
| 9 | 3 |
| 3 | 1 |

Пояснение к результату:

**Первая строка**: коммент с id **11** принадлежит посту 2. У этого поста последние комменты(**10** и **11**) принадлежат одному и тому же юзеру(**1**) а так как перед ними идёт коммент(**8**) от другого юзера(**3**) то от него и начинается отсчет

**Вторая строка**: в зачёт попали комменты **9** **7** **4** так как они последние от одного и того же юзера

**Третья строка**: тут он вообще один у поста

---

Как достать id последнего коммента для поста понятно. Группируем по **post_id** и берём **MAX(id)**. Но вот как достать количество последних комментариев поста от одного и того же юзера - не понятно. Пробовал оконные функции, но ничего не вышло. Также пытался как то это сделать через **ARRAY_AGG** что бы разложить id комментов в одну строку с **post_id**, но не придумал что с этим потом делать.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```sql
WITH 
cte1 AS (
    SELECT *, 
           FIRST_VALUE(user_id) OVER (PARTITION BY post_id ORDER BY id DESC) last_user
    FROM comments
),
cte2 AS (
    SELECT *,
           SUM((user_id <> last_user)::INT) OVER (PARTITION BY post_id ORDER BY id DESC) another_user
    FROM cte1
)
SELECT MAX(id) comment_id,
       COUNT(*) last_user_comments_count
FROM cte2
WHERE another_user = 0
GROUP BY post_id
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=fb9526755f0b40cea88150e3ca9cc349

Comment: Работает как надо. Но не могли бы Вы объяснить, как работает строка **SUM((user_id <> last_user)::INT) OVER (PARTITION BY post_id ORDER BY id DESC) another_user** и почему там учитываются не все комментарии поста, а идут на сужение? Как такое происходит? Разве оконная функция не все записи учитывает?

Comment: @NoName Первый CTE просто получает user_id последнего пользователя. А во втором CTE сравнивается текущий и этот последний, и считается количество этих несовпадений. Затем, отбирая в наружном запросе только нули, мы и получаем только нужное.